# Partition Alignment in AWS SSD EBS

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, aws, storage

I'm setting up a new SQL Server 2008 r2 in AWS with IO1 SSD EBS volumes.  My smaller EBS volumes are aligned correctly when they were formatted but the larger volumes, 3TB, are not because they used GPT instead of MBR.

I'm going though the setup check list in Brent Ozar's First Responder Kit and referencing another [post that is asking generally about SSDs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158734/ssds-and-64k-sectors/159523) as well a [document from AWS](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/best-practices-for-deploying-microsoft-sql-server-on-aws.pdf) to ensure I have it optimized however I'm not finding anything of relevance when it comes to disk partition alignments for GPT or if it's necessary to do for IO1 SSD EBS Volumes in AWS.

Is partition alignment needed when it comes to AWS' SSD EBS volumes?
Is there a best practice for what the alignment should be for GPT formatted volumes?

Comment: I stopped at “a new SQL Server 2008 R2” - why on earth is this no longer even remotely supported version the one you’re choosing in August 2019?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Money for licensing

Comment: Where are you buying a valid 2008 R2 license today?

Comment: @AaronBertrand we have mobility on our existing per socket licensing

Comment: Trust me I’m not happy about having to stay on it either. Besides the out of support it’s becoming harder to find the .net framework installations needed