# In a SAN based SQL server, where does the 64K allocation block size formatting need to occur?

Tags: sql-server, san

I understand sql data and log file drive must be formatted 64K allocation block size.

In a SAN environment, there are physical disks which are part of the SAN storage pool; and from the storage pool we create LUN; and then assign the LUN to the Hyper-V and we create disks out of the LUN. Then a disk is assigned to the SQL server VM. Volumes (drives) are then created from this disk for the data and log file.

Suppose I format the drives to be of 64K allocation block size, then does that really help? Or do I need to format the physical disks in the SAN?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSDs and 64K sectors](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158734/ssds-and-64k-sectors)

Answer (score 2):

I’m assuming you have in mind the cluster size, aka allocation unit size and the recommendations for SQL Server on Windows. This is an attribute of the filesystem, and thus doesn’t directly determine configuration or behavior of storage at the many layers of the disk IO stack below the filesystem.

Note the best practice of using a 64k cluster size is not an absolute: most laptop installs of SQL Server use a 4k cluster size for txlogs and data files due to the filesystem(s) they use and do perfectly fine (given the expectations of a laptop install of SQL Server).

The cluster size of a filesystem determines the minimum “size on disk” for a file in that filesystem, and the minimal incremental growth on disk that can occur to that file on the filesystem.

The filesystem is an organization of potentially many sequential “runs” of clusters  with size from 1 to n clusters which make up the files on the filesystem. If there’s a filesystem of cluster size 4k with 1024 files that are each of “size” 512 bytes, the aggregate “size on disk” will be 4 mb. If the cluster size were instead 64k, the aggregate size would be 64 mb.

The cluster size does not directly limit the size of individual disk IOs for SQL Server or any other application. Just affects the organization and accounting within the filesystem - especially if there are many files in the filesystem which grow in a pattern that causes them to be interleaved with each other.

So, the “wasted space” is a consideration for filesystems with thousands of small files - flat files for import or xml files or such.
But if there’s only 1 large file in the filesystem (this is my recommendation for high performance databases with the exception of tempdb), having the larger 64k cluster size allows more efficient metadata for the filesystem with no appreciable increase in “wasted space”.

It’s important to note that the relatively new 1 mb cluster size is gaining momentum.

On a brand-new system that expects extremely large data files I’d check it out. if all files in the filesystem grow in a multiple of 1 mb anyway, there will be no wasted space. (I recommend especially watching how the sparse files for SQL Server snapshot databases and the internal snapshots for checkdb/checktable interact with a 1 mb cluster size. the snapshot itself grows by 64kb extent at a time afaik, but i’m not sure if after each 1 mb cluster is added to the sparse file all of the 1 mb is eventually used by the sparse file or not.) And again, the system may benefit from the more streamlined accounting of 1 mb clusters compared to 64k clusters.

Comment: For example - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/sql-server-ec2-best-practices/ntfs-size.html - here it says to use 64K

Comment: Sigh. the reasoning is incomplete at best in that doc. >> "The atomic unit of storage in SQL Server is a page, which is 8 KB in size. Eight physically contiguous pages make up an extent (which is 64 KB in size). SQL Server uses extents to store data. Therefore, on a SQL Server machine, the NTFS allocation unit size for hosting SQL database files (including tempdb) should be 64 KB." The cluster size only has direct meaning for filesystem allocation and tracking.

Comment: So 64K is best practice? In your answer you have given 1mb?

Comment: @variable yes, 64kb cluster size/allocation unit size is the current best practice for file systems that contain only SQL Server database data or log files. But it has nothing to do with any formatting or stripe/strip configuration of lower level storage like SAN or direct-attached storage. Also not strictly tied to the 64kb extent size of SQL Server.

Comment: @variable the cluster size determines maximum size of the filesystem, and together with the maximum number of fragments per file in the NTFS filesystem (useLargeFRS or not) determines the smallest possible size at which a file could run into the “maximum fragments” limitation.

Comment: @variable in the near future as file sizes continue to grow and people continue to look for various performance efficiencies i expect 1 mb cluster size to get attention. Max filesystem size would grow again 16-fold and tracking of large files would again become more efficient. But i’m not sure how 1 mb cluster size will interact with sparse files for snapshots - will there be wasted space for every 64kb allocation even if adjacent to other snapshot 64 kb extents in the source file?

Comment: Ok so for now 64k is best practice then and not 1mb.

Comment: @variable correct - afaik no-one has documented how the 1 mb cluster size behaves in a sparse file which tracks changes based on 64 kb extents, so anyone using 1 mb cluster size might be jumping ahead a bit.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to use 64kb allocation block size formatting at the SAN physical disk/LUN level? Or this is only to be done at SQL server Windows drive level?